# Android resource IDs suddenly not final, switch()'es broken

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-errors

PREAMBLE: this question is quite obsolete, it was written when the preferred Android dev environment was Eclipse with the Android plugin.

---

I had a Java Android project for a while. Today, I've updated the Android dev tools to the Google's latest. And the project broke - I get a bunch of "case expressions must be constant expressions" compilation error messages.

Turns out that the R.java file is being now generated differently. Formerly, it would have a bunch of

```
public static final int MyID=0x12340000;
```

statements; now, it looks (after a clean/rebuild) like this:

```
public static int MyID=0x12340000;
```

`final` is gone. So all switches on resource IDs that I had (and I had a few) are wrong. What happened, please? Is it just me? What's the rationale here? Is it documented anywhere? Can I bring `final` back somehow?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This happened about yesterday, when the SDK/ADT 14 got released:

> As of ADT 14, resource constants in library projects are no longer
>   final. This is explained in greater detail in http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

There's a quickfix available from ADT 14: http://tools.android.com/recent/switchstatementconversion

To quote from the rationale:

> When multiple library projects are combined, the actual values of the
>   fields (which must be unique) could collide. Before ADT 14, all fields
>   were final, so as a result, all libraries had to have all their
>   resources and associated Java code recompiled along with the main
>   project whenever they were used. This was bad for performance, since
>   it made builds very slow. It also prevented distributing library
>   projects that didn't include the source code, limiting the usage scope
>   of library projects.
>
> The reason the fields are no longer final is that it means that the library jars can be compiled once and reused directly in other projects. As well as allowing distributing binary version of library projects (coming in r15), this makes for much faster builds.

Comment: Makes sense, actually. I see where they're coming from. The fact that Android libraries were just linked sources as opposed to, well, compiled libraries, has been a minor pain point for me for some time. Also, kudos to Google for providing a magic refactorer.

Comment: This is just a consequence of an idiotic design decision by the Android team. Whenever you see some generated file with a bunch of magic number constants, you should look at it funny.  Thanks, Google for breaking a bunch of your developers' source code due to complete lack of foresight.  Public static ints.  Much better?!

Comment: This answer is marked as solution - but I don't see it...
Very nice discussions, suggestions, documentation links and etc only...
What is concrete solution? What should I change in my code to fix the issue - please in a few words? Or no solution? - then please answer in one word: "no". ?

Comment: @RussiaDroneFlights Did you read any of the links? They say to use if-else clauses instead of switch statements if you need to do someting conditionally with resource IDs. Switch statements would require the IDs to be final, which they haven't been for slightly over nine years now.

Comment: This will makes you do a lot of extra work and do a lot of unnecessary modify of your code, just add `android.nonFinalResIds=false` in the gradle.properties file will working.

Comment: Bad Android design, ids must be final.

Comment: @applixy - I am doing this.  I think I love you!  This is saving my day!!!  I just spent 2 hours researching this and your little comment here is the ONLY good answer I have found.  ty.

Answer (score 14):

You could switch over to using If/Else statements and the warning will go away.

Sample:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        //finds which button was pressed
        final int buttonView = v.getId();
        String current = fromEditText.getText().toString();
        if (buttonView == R.id.bA) {
            current += getString(R.string.a);
        } 
  }
```

Comment: ❤️ Good one!

Answer (score 13):

Just add parentheses:

```
switch (view.getId()) {
    case (R.id.view1):
        break;
    case (R.id.view2):
        break;
}
```

Comment: Why does this work?  And is it safe to do?

Comment: @SMBiggs I think it makes it some kind of constant, not only a reference.
I use it some months in production mode with many customers and yet i've not gotten any crash or complaint.

Comment: The case statements are hardcoded at compile time. What you need is the resource to be environment constant and it is not. with or without parentheses.. This is similar with: "final int VIEW_ID_1 = R.id.view1;" The switch will fail if the resource will be changed later because it will no longer match the hardcoded resource.

Comment: The only thing this does is potentially make the detector miss this case. But it **doesn't** solve the case when the ids will actually be non-final (the Java compiler will not compile this code then). So it's a band-aid at best (all it does it silence the warning, but it doesn't fix the problem).

Answer (score 6):

Google recommends you use **if/else conditions**

http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

To change them automatically you can place the caret on the `switch` keyword and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows (<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on Mac) and select **Replace 'switch' with 'if'**

Answer (score 4):

This is because in new AGP verion, Google make all rescours ids non final, add `android.nonFinalResIds=false` in your `gradle.properties` file in the root directory of your project to make sure the AGP generate final res ids will make you avoid modify your code.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev well i can confirm it also just happened again now in gradle version 8.0

Comment: It's odd that I wrote an entire android app (thankfully the only one I ever had to write) in 2017 and the auto generated code and "recommended" code was all using switch statements.  (sure, I targeted an older Android OS version... still.  Very messed up situation).  This makes me question the wisdom of Java `switch()` statements entirely.  It never would have mattered if the hardware didn't fail and I didn't have to "recompile" to "re-target' a newer phone and end up practically re-writing the entire application.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)!

```
android {
    ...
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with menus. The original question was mostly about menu IDs.

Comment: Adds a lot of classes and also doesn't actually fix the problem, it just uses another way to identify and work with views.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this snipped in your module-level `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    ...
    lintOptions {
        disable 'NonConstantResourceId'
    }
}
```

More:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#gradle

Comment: Any disadvantage of doing disabling lint option.

Comment: Careful, this just disables the Lint Warning, it does not actually fix the problem in itself.