# Android Studio application module to a library module

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio and I have an application module that I want to convert to a library module.

In my application module `build.gradle` file, I've tried changing

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

also removing my `applicationId` tag.

This is giving me gradle build errors, and I do not know how to proceed.

Gradle Build Message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

And 18 of these:

```
error: constant expression required
```

Where I'm referencing to my `R.java` files in `MainActivity.java`.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_settings: //gives error

            break;

        case R.id.action_share: //gives error

            break;

        case R.id.action_about: //gives error

            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I've been searching on how to convert an application module to a library module for a while, and above should have solved my problem so I don't know why I am getting these errors. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since ADT 14 resource constants in library projects are no longer final. 
You can find more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7840985/759007 .

You should replace switch with if-else statements. If you are using IntelliJ/Android Studio you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on switch and choose Replace 'switch' with 'if'.