# Are resources final in Android?

Tags: android

As explained in http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields, resource ids are not final (in ADT 14). So a check with *switch* is broken (see: [Android resource IDs suddenly not final, switch()'es broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840914/android-resource-ids-suddenly-not-final-switches-broken)).
However after opening R.java you can see that there are *final* resources.
So, what to use - *if* or *switch*? What versions of SDK require *if* statement?
A Lint does not alert if I write

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.llBirthday:
        ...
        break;
    case R.id.llCity:
        ...
        break;
}
```

Comment: Both will work, i guess its a question of preference. When you refer to R.id.SomeId, You are referring to R, and R is generated when you compile your app, so it should always work. It's been practice with google for a while now. For safety i always use if, because case is dependent on primitive int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ids are converted to a unique integer value and by switching on the value of `R.id.myvalue` that int value will always map to that resource.

The linked question is from 2011.

As for `if` or `switch`, if you have only a couple of values then an if statement might be better, a longer list then a switch, which is programming basics. Please note this is not set in stone. [When to use If-else if-else over switch statments and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427760/when-to-use-if-else-if-else-over-switch-statments-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Thank you, Ms Yvette, I understand. So, I think, Google changes of 2011 are now deprecated and we can use *switch*.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `if else` or `switch` both and both will work. And as you are using `R.id.yourResource` which will convert to an int thats why both `if else` and `switch` work.

Comment: I agree with you. I was fearing that an app could fail in some cases if using switch. But Google restored *final* in R.java, so no problem again.